# Find double integral boundaries.

Tags: integration

I have to solve this integral

$$\int\int_D x^2y {\,\rm d}x {\,\rm d}y$$

where the domain D is given as follows: D: {$x^2+y^2<D^2, y\ge0$}

My problem is that i don't know how can i get my boundaries
$$\int_?^?\int_?^? x^2y {\,\rm d}x {\,\rm d}y$$

Comment: Using polar coordinates is OK?

Comment: Yes, I should use polar coordinates

Comment: First, *draw* the domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the integral
$$\iint_D x^2y {\,\rm d}x {\,\rm d}y$$
over the domain $D:\{x^2+y^2<D^2, y\ge0\}$ it is best to transform to polar coordinates. See the following picture, I marked the domain by filling with gray lines.

> [image]

Hence the transformed domain reads $D:\{r<D, 0\le\theta\le\pi\}$. The jacobian determinant for polar coordinates is ${\rm d}A=r{\,\rm d}r{\,\rm d}\theta$ (no derivation here). Furthermore
$$
\pmatrix{x\cr y} = \pmatrix{r\cos\theta\cr r\sin\theta}
$$
With these rules the integral transforms to
$$\begin{aligned}
  \iint_D x^2y {\,\rm d}x {\,\rm d}y&=\iint_D (r\cos\theta)^2r\sin\theta\;r{\,\rm d}r{\,\rm d}\theta\cr
  &=\int_0^D{\rm d}r\int_0^\pi{\rm d}\theta\; r^4\cos^2\theta\sin\theta\cr
  &=\int_0^D{\rm d}r\; r^4 \int_0^\pi{\rm d}\theta\;\cos^2\theta\sin\theta\cr
  &= {1\over5}D^5 \int_0^\pi{\rm d}\theta\;\cos^2\theta\sin\theta\cr
  &= {1\over5}D^5 \left[-{1\over3}\cos^3\theta\right]_0^\pi\cr
  &= {1\over5}D^5 {2\over3}\cr
  &= {2\over15}D^5\cr
\end{aligned}$$

Answer (score 0):

One way to translate the information given about the domain of integration into the upper and lower bounds on the double integral is to first draw a picture of $D$ if possible. This will help you determine the order of integration. In your example, $D$ is a filled in disk of radius less than or equal to $D$. Using $D$ for bot the set that is the domain and also for the radius of this particular disk is kind of an abuse of notation but we understand there is a difference through context. Once you have a picture of the domain, you can now ask questions about its simplicity. Graphically, a region $D$ in the plane is vertically simple or is Type I if it is possible to place a test rectangle vertically over the domain and slide it horizontally keeping the intersection of the rectangle with the domain always between functions of $x$. viz:

\begin{align}
\text{Lower: Rectangle}\bigcap D = f_1(x)\\
\text{Upper: Rectangle}\bigcap D = f_2(x)\\
\end{align}

If this is true then we can integrate in the order $dydx$. The order $dxdy$ is treated in much the same way except now your testing rectangle is placed horizontally and adjusted vertically. Keep in mind that we want to fill out the region $D$ by "sweeping out" its area. So thinking this way we construct an "adjustable" straight line connecting the lower boundary of $D_\text{lower}= f_1(x)$ to the upper boundary of $D_\text{upper}: f_2(x)$ and then if $a$ is the left-most point of $D$ and $b$ is the right-most point of $D$, we finish sweeping out the area by taking our vertical line and running it across from $a$ to $b$. In the end what we've constructed is the following:

\begin{align}
\int_a^b\int_{f_1(x)}^{f_2(x)}g(x,y)dydx
\end{align}

where $g$ is some integrable function. In your case, a circle is simple in both directions and so its up to you on how to do it. It is often the case that $g$ is easier to integrate in a particular order and so you can use that as a decision maker. Hope this helps